# List the words in a vocabulary according to occurrence in a text corpus, with Scikit-Learn CountVectorizer

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-extraction, countvectorizer

I have fitted a `CountVectorizer` to some documents in `scikit-learn`. I would like to see all the terms and their corresponding frequency in the text corpus, in order to select stop-words. For example

```
'and' 123 times, 'to' 100 times, 'for' 90 times, ... and so on
```

Is there any built-in function for this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If `cv` is your `CountVectorizer` and `X` is the vectorized corpus, then

```
zip(cv.get_feature_names(),
    np.asarray(X.sum(axis=0)).ravel())
```

returns a list of `(term, frequency)` pairs for each distinct term in the corpus that the `CountVectorizer` extracted.

(The little `asarray` + `ravel` dance is needed to work around some quirks in `scipy.sparse`.)

Comment: Thanks! But they are not ordered, but I managed to do that: for tuple in sorted( occ_list ,key=lambda idx: idx[1] ): print tuple[0] +' ' +  str(tuple[1]). The problem is that characters åäö are not printed out. I have set the coding to utf8.

Comment: Also are you sure that get_feature_names() will have the terms ordered according to their index in the term-frequency matrix? I have found out that cv.get_feature_names() and cv.vocabulary_.keys() does not have the same order.

Comment: @user1506145: `dict.keys` doesn't guarantee any order; that's exactly why `get_feature_names` exists.

Comment: Sorry to dredge this topic up, but how would you make a _vectorized corpus_, `X`, from a simple string like "This is the example that we will make an example of."

Answer (score 5):

There is no built-in. I have found a faster way to do it based on [Ando Saabas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288497/find-the-most-common-term-in-scikit-learn-classifier):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer 
texts = ["Hello world", "Python makes a better world"]
vec = CountVectorizer().fit(texts)
bag_of_words = vec.transform(texts)
sum_words = bag_of_words.sum(axis=0)
words_freq = [(word, sum_words[0, idx]) for word, idx in vec.vocabulary_.items()]
sorted(words_freq, key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

**output**

```
[('world', 2), ('python', 1), ('hello', 1), ('better', 1), ('makes', 1)]
```