# Find the Most common term in Scikit-learn classifier

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm following the [example in Scikit learn docs](http://scikit-learn.github.io/scikit-learn-tutorial/working_with_text_data.html) where `CountVectorizer` is used on some dataset.

**Question**: `count_vect.vocabulary_.viewitems()` lists all the terms and their frequencies. How do you sort them by the number of occurances?

`sorted( count_vect.vocabulary_.viewitems() )` does not seem to work.

Comment: Hi! maybe you would like see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48490046/1093674

Answer (score 16):

`vocabulary_.viewitems()` does not in fact list the terms and their frequencies, instead its a mapping from terms to their indexes. The frequencies (per document) are returned by the fit_transform method, which returns a sparse (coo) matrix, where the rows are documents and columns the words (with column indexes mapped to words via vocabulary_). You can get the total frequencies for example by

```
matrix = count_vect.fit_transform(doc_list)
freqs = zip(count_vect.get_feature_names(), matrix.sum(axis=0))    
# sort from largest to smallest
print sorted(freqs, key=lambda x: -x[1])
```

Comment: You need to replace `matrix.sum(axis=0)` to `matrix.sum(axis=0).tolist()[0]`, since matrix.sum() returns a matrix.